# How to divide post on many pages in joomla cms

Tags: joomla

How to break article for many little pages?
with navigation at page footer?

for example:

pages: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

Answer (score 1):

There's a Pagebreak button at the bottom of the article manager that you can use to do this.  You'll have to fiddle with the layout to get the navigation on the footer.

http://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_a_long_Article_into_multiple_linked_pages